# How to read / understand integrals involving high-dimensional Vectors and Matrices

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, matrix-calculus

While reading [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1901.06950), I came across the following equation (in Section 3.5):

$$L(X | M) = - \log \int{p(X|W,Z)p(Z)p(W)dW dZ }$$

Where $X$ and $Z$ are vectors and $W$ is a matrix.

I have seen multivariate integrals, but I'm not sure how to read or understand equations like this which involve both vectors and matrices in integrals.

My question hence is: How would someone read this equation and what field of maths I need to look into to get more details about this and become comfortable reading literature involving these?